# No named parameter with the name 'errorBuilder' in youtube_player_flutter package in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

After adding 
**import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';**
and run my flutter project I got this error in my console.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device CRO U00...

Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/youtube_player_flutter-7.0.0+3/lib/src/player/youtube_player.dart:427:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'errorBuilder'.
          errorBuilder: (context, _, __) => Container(),
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart:332:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  Image.network(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/youtube_player_flutter-7.0.0+3/lib/src/player/youtube_player.dart:417:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'errorBuilder'.
        errorBuilder: (context, _, __) => Image.network(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart:332:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  Image.network(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Restarted application in 1,991ms.
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This parameter has been added recently to flutter (13 march), in version 1.17.0-3.2.pre

see : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/73b2895ff13c5e6d07702ea5ad4cf58930c07582#diff-9f13824e3ca5f82861d3d33ce1d670fd

Upgrade your flutter version and it should be good.

If you can't upgrade your flutter version, consider downgrade the version of your youtube plugin (working without errorBuilder on my side with youtube_player_version 6.1.0+7).

Comment: all are up to date